# Cllocationmanager Didupdatelocation delegate not getting called without internet

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I am currently working on a location based ios application. I am using `didupdatelocation` delegate method for showing user's current location. It works fine when I connect my device to internet. But when I disconnect the internet, it behaves strange and `didupdatelocation` is not getting called further. Please give a solution.
**EDITED** with code details

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init]; // initializing locationManager
    locationManager.delegate = self; // we set the delegate of locationManager to self. 
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; // setting the accuracy

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];  //requesting location updates
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"There was an error retrieving your location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [errorAlert show];
    NSLog(@"Error: %@",error.description);
}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *crnLoc = [locations lastObject];
    latitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",crnLoc.coordinate.latitude];
    longitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",crnLoc.coordinate.longitude];
    altitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f m",crnLoc.altitude];
    speed.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f m/s", crnLoc.speed];
}
```

Comment: without internet connection CLlocation manager can't access your current location. Try with internet

Comment: @SarathiOS: My application demands offline navigation (without internet) :(

Comment: it will show your current location but u can't map it in on a map view without internet.

Comment: @Sarath iOS : Sometimes it works fine but sometimes it won't , maping is not an issue because i am not using mapview i just want to call these delegate method.

Comment: I have a app with similar requirements. CLLocationManager delegate methods are called. Show how you instantiate the CLLocationManager and some of the relevant code. Also do you check for errors of CLLocationManager?

Comment: Do you receive any didFailWithError calls when it behaves "strange" ?

Comment: @Volker: no nothing in error..

Comment: your CLLocationManager instance is still alive when not connected? So you don't remove it by accident or so?

Comment: yes its alive and i am keeping this  cllocationmanager instance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76049/discussion-between-anshad-r-and-volker).

Comment: How are you testing? Indoors/Outdoors?  When you say without Internet do you mean no cell and no WiFi or just no WiFi? If you are testing indoors, without Cell or WiFi, GPS will act very slowly and erratic as it tries to get satellite signals.  Also since you have your accuracy set to  `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` it will require more satellites.  Try going outside to test and see how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ANSHAD per your comment, if you are using an older iPad without GPS, the only way you can get location data is with WiFi so if you turn off WiFi, you will not get location updates. If you want GPS without WiFi you can buy an external GPS module [see here](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=bl_sr_gps?ie=UTF8&field-brandtextbin=Bad+Elf&node=172526)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the base GPS of the iPhone which works without the internet too. To access it you need to use the CoreLocation framework.

You can refer to this : [CoreLocation methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html) to use the GPS data.

Let me know if any other help required.

Comment: sorry,my application is only for ipad devics :(

Comment: Yes, that GPS chip is available in all ios devices. so will work in ipad too. please refer:  `https://github.com/shawngrimes/Location-and-Map-Sample`

Comment: Actually seperate gps module is available for some of the ios devices only like iphone, 3g ipads  etc..